# MinLength/Range Data Annotation does not work in NUnit test

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, data-annotations

If I use MinLen and Range in my model class the test doesn't throw the exception I expect.

MaxLength instead works as expected.

I have the same behaviour also using other db as sqlite, sqlserver.

```
[TestFixture]
public class PostgreSqlRangeFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void TestRange_MustThrow()
    {
        using (var ctx = new LocalDbContext()) {
            ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

            User user = new User() { FirstName = "12", LastName = "too short", Age = -100 };
            ctx.Users.Add(user);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class LocalDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        const string psw = "marcos";
        string dbName = "test_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss.fff");
        var cs = $"Host=192.168.99.100;Username=postgres;Password={psw};Database={dbName}";
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(cs);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0,150)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: These data annotations are not used/considered by EF Core (currently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF Core is using only part of attributes provided by these namsespaces:

> System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
> System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

It seems like only **Required** and **MaxLength** should work in your case. Check this -> [EF Core Annotations](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes)

The rest of attributes can be used in model validation in ASP.NET Core API's --> [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Correct. This list should really be provided by official EF Core documentation rather than external source, but since they didn't, it is fine.

Comment: I agree, it really grind my gears that stuff like that isn't just put in one place. They even [have page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt) explaining usage with examples, I guess that putting table with one-line explanation wouldn't hurt them so much, would it?